# PHP / Symfony2, failing to load

Tags: php, symfony, web, frameworks

I've installed symfony using composer and have set it up. I've used php composer.phar create project symfony/framework-standard-edition projectName.

This seems to work fine.

When i start the php web server `php console server:run`, it starts okay but when i go on localhost:8000, i get the following errors:

`Warning: require(app_dev.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in .....`

`( ! ) Fatal error: require(): Failed opening required 'app_dev.php' (include_path='.:/usr/local/php5/lib/php') in ......`

But, when i open the project in Netbeans using a PHP web server, and set the web root path to the web folder, within the symfony folder. It all works perfectly.

Any ideas?

Cheers

Comment: What happens if you go to localhost:8000/web/app_dev.php?

Comment: Exact same Error, it's almsot like the Root directory folder is different some how

Comment: Do you have enabled mod rewrite in your PHP server?

Answer (score 3):

If you launch server from app folder Symfony will crash.
So try this:

```
cd ~/Symfony 
php app/console server:run
```